How to prevent lead poisoning from PCB?
I just bought a PCB that has leaded HASL, so what should I do so I don't get poisoned? There was an unleaded HASL option but I wanted to save a couple of bucks. Mayo Clinic says that lead poisoning is fatal and can happen after months or years of exposure to lead. So, how do you prevent it? I need to solder some components onto the PCB with unleaded solder, so would they stick to each other? Also, would the fumes from soldering on leaded HASL be more toxic than unleaded solder? Once I'm done soldering all the components, how should I get rid of all of the leftover lead?

I see that a lot of people say I shouldn't eat the solder but if it gets onto your fingers and then into your food, wouldn't that be bad? I am planning to put the board outside, so there is no enclosure because it has buttons, and while I can make an enclosure for the buttons, it would take a lot of work. So, if an unexpecting person accidentally gets some lead dust on their fingers, would they get poisoned?

Metallic lead as used in solder is toxic, yes, but nowhere near as toxic as the lead compounds formerly used in leaded paint and leaded gasoline. There is very little risk of lead poisoning from working with leaded solder, as long as you aren't horribly reckless with it. Just wash your hands afterward. There's more risk of injury from inhaling decomposition products from the flux fumes, and the fumes from leaded solder are even typically less bad for you than those from lead-free solder, due to different fluxes used.

Don't lick the board or suck on solder. Lastly, do not eat solder. Otherwise, you will be fine.

Chill.
What you need to do to not get lead poisoning from a leaded HASL board is the following:

Don't go to a pharmacy and buy a very strong acid
Then, as you not return from the pharmacy you've not been, don't start to dissolve your PCB
Don't drink the heavy metal salt solution you did not produce that way
When you're finished not drinking this heavy metal salt solution, do not not repeat step 1 through 3 for a couple more boards.

Seriously, lead is a dangerous toxin. But: It's hard to get into your body through – the vapors you are exposed to when soldering are almost completely solder flux and other impurities, and not very much lead. Maybe don't solder for days in a small, unventilated room? Less because of the lead, more because that flux fume – not really dangerous if you're not soldering 5 days a week for years with insufficient ventilation. But still prone to give you a headache if you solder without letting in fresh air and without a fume ventilator for hours on end.
Lead poising in the real world typically takes one of a couple of ways:

Lead from contaminated food / water. Think about Romans drinking wine from a lead container for their whole life. It takes effort to bring lead into solution, so an acid milieu like wine is bad. Works with water lead pipes, as well, but typically much slower. But then again, a human (hopefully) drinks more water than wine from leaded vessels, so that's why tragedies like the Flint Water Crisis are a thing.
Lead from leaded gasoline: We used to blow lead compounds in a bio-absorbable composition into the air from every car's exhaust. That was really damaging on a global scale, and we stopped adding tetraethyllead to gasoline.
Occupational hazards involving handling lots of lead: If you're working at a lead factory, or at the machine applying leaded HASL to customer boards, you should probably make sure you don't inhale lead dust and other lead compounds. After all, unlike John Doe, you're not handling the lead in maybe 10 boards a day, but the lead for 10,000 boards an hour – and in a shape where it's much more volatile.

So, you're worrying too much – solder in a well-ventilated room and/or with a fume extractor, don't eat with your hands when handling lead. The dose is what makes a toxin dangerous – and the doses you could reasonably expose yourself are really tiny.
I'd agree with Drew, if you can, use lead-free solder. Unlike what you often read, not all lead-free solders have a melting point higher than that of all leaded solders — there's different formulations. But again, you're not doing this every day. Just as you going to the top of a high mountain exposes you to carcinogen UV radiation, as long as you don't do it for hours every day, and take basic precautions, it's very very unlikely to cause cancer.

Yeah, I'd suggest: don't lick your PCBs. Wash your hands before eating.

Just my two cents. Because the risk of lead poisoning from hobbyist soldering is so small (assuming you wash your hands, and don't lick anything etc) and because I find leaded solder easier to work with than lead-free, I feel the benefits outweigh the risks, for me. So, I personally do not recommend using unleaded solder unless regulations apply. Others are free to choose differently.

As Hearth said, only basic precautions are required.
After handling the PCB or solder, wash your hands.
When you're soldering tiny lead balls may splatter about, creating lead contamination in your work area. You shouldn't eat in this area.
The temperature at which lead solder melts is too low for there to be significant evaporation of lead. Even so, it's best if your soldering iron is temp controlled and set to the right temperature, so you don't heat the solder hotter than  necessary. The solder smoke is full of evaporated flux compounds though so you still shouldn't breath it. It's best to use a fume extractor of some kind.
The resulting PCB contains a significant amount of lead, so depending on how you dispose of it lead may leach into the environment. This is probably not significant for a few hobby PCBs but it certainly mattered back when they were all made with leaded solder.
If you're worried about lead exposure (I personally am) I recommend using lead free HASL and solder next time. In my opinion if you have an iron that's temp controlled and set to the right temperature, it melts and flows just fine.

But the solder was unleaded. Only the HASL will contain lead.

This is general advice for dealing with lead solder. If you apply lead free solder to the leaded pcb board then the resulting blobs will have a tiny bit of lead in them. Same rules apply, but of course the amount of lead in everything is significantly lower.
